# Fill select boxes using ajax. Better way of doing it

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML page that has four select boxes. When my page loads I want to fill them with data (using AJAX). Until here it's okay.

The problem is that I want to show, in each one, the chosen value. Let's say, I have `TABLE_A` with the `column ID_Name` and the `TABLE_B` has all the names. I can fill the chosen select with all the names but I am not able to automatically show the selected `ID_Name`.

The same for the others chosen selected. I tried to assign the `ID_Name` to a variable but it is not working because I do not know witch one of the AJAX scripts is loading first. Sometimes it fills the selected elements first and get the ID after, but sometimes it makes the reverse. How can I avoid this?

My script so far::

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

        var id_contacto = 0;
        var recebido_por = 0;
        var responder_por = 0;

        // Get general Data
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/c_consultas.php?tipo_acao=consulta_detalhes_consulta&id_consulta='+getUrlVars()['id_consulta'],
            type: 'post',
            data: { tag: 'getData'},
            dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, record) {                            
                            if ($.isNumeric(index)) { 
                                $('#cliente').val(record.cliente_nome).show();
                                id_contacto = record.id_contacto;
                                $('#ref_consulta').val(record.referenciaconsulta).show();
                                $('#titulo').val(record.tituloconsulta).show();
                                recebido_por = record.recebido_por;
                                responder_por = record.responder_por;
                                $('#consulta_notas').val(record.notas_consulta).show();
                            }
                    })
                }
            }
        });            


        // Get List of type of comunication (received by)
        $.ajax({
                url: 'php/listagens.php?tipo_lista=recebido_por',
                type: 'post',
                data: { tag: 'getData'},
                dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                    $('#recebido_por').empty();
                    $('#recebido_por').append($("<option />").val('').text("Selecione uma opção...").attr('disabled','disabled').attr('style','display:none;'));
                        if (data.success) {
                            $.each(data, function (index, record) {                            
                                if ($.isNumeric(index))                                     

                                    if (record.ID == recebido_por){
                                        $('#recebido_por').append($("<option selected='selected'/>").val(record.ID).text(record.meio_comunicacao));
                                    } else {
                                        $('#recebido_por').append($("<option />").val(record.ID).text(record.meio_comunicacao));
                                    }
                            });
                            $('#recebido_por').trigger("liszt:updated");
                        }
                    }
            });            

        // Get type of comunication, again... (respond by)
        $.ajax({
                url: 'php/listagens.php?tipo_lista=recebido_por',
                type: 'post',
                data: { tag: 'getData'},
                dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                    $('#responder_por').empty();
                    $('#responder_por').append($("<option />").val('').text("Selecione uma opção...").attr('disabled','disabled').attr('style','display:none;'));
                        if (data.success) {
                            $.each(data, function (index, record) {                            
                                if ($.isNumeric(index))                                     

                                    if (record.ID == responder_por){
                                        $('#responder_por').append($("<option selected='selected'/>").val(record.ID).text(record.meio_comunicacao));
                                    } else {
                                        $('#responder_por').append($("<option />").val(record.ID).text(record.meio_comunicacao));
                                    }
                            });
                            $('#responder_por').trigger("liszt:updated");
                        }
                    }
            });            




        //List of Internal contacts
        $.ajax({
                url: 'php/c_consultas.php?tipo_acao=listagem_contactos_internos&id_consulta='+getUrlVars()['id_consulta'],
                type: 'post',
                data: { tag: 'getData'},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#contacto').empty();
                    $('#contacto').append($("<option />").val('').text("Selecione um contacto...").attr('disabled','disabled').attr('style','display:none;'));

                    if (data.success) {
                        var linha = "";
                        $.each(data, function (index, record) {
                            if ($.isNumeric(index)) { 
                                if (this.ID == id_contacto){
                                    $('#contacto').append($("<option selected='selected'/>").val(this.ID).text(this.nome));
                                } else {
                                    $('#contacto').append($("<option />").val(this.ID).text(this.nome));
                                }
                            }
                        })

                        $('#contacto').trigger("liszt:updated");
                    }
                }
            });            
}); // FIM Document(ready).
</script>
```

Comment: When a page loads it's not supposed to load with a certain sequence?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this (in my opinion) is to pass everything back to the client in a single AJAX call.  Define the JSON object as multiple rows (in this case 4) of the following: id, pipe-delimited string of select list values (listString), currentValue.  On the Success branch, parse the json object, split the pipe-delimited string, load the options based on the controlID, and set the value after attaching the option list to the select list.

```
if ('setSels' in serverResponse) {
        var setSel = serverResponse.setSels;
        wklen = setSel.length;
        var optVal = '';
        var valList;
        var j;
        for (i = 0; i < wklen; i++) {
            wkEl = jQuery('#' + setSel[i].id);
            if (wkEl.length) {
                valList = setSel[i].listString.split("|");
                optVal = '<option value=""></option>';
                for (j = 0; j < valList.length; j++) {
                    optVal += '<option value="' + valList[j] + '">' + valList[j] + '</option>';
                }
                jQuery(wkEl).html(optVal).val(setSel[i].currentValue);
            }
            else {
                alert('cannot find ' + setSel[i].id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: LIKE! :) I will try it, but first I have to study a little bit (I'm a beginner in this). Thanks for your help. I will give you my feedback

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same using a callback, not got time to fully explain but heres the code so you should be able to figure it out.

```
function CascadeDropDowns(parentClass, childClass, action, callback) {
  var DropDownId = $(parentClass + " option:selected").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Terminals_configuration/" + action,
    data: { DropDownId: DropDownId },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    error: function () {
      alert("An error occurred.");
    },
    success: function (data) {
      var items = "";
      $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
      });
      $(childClass).html(items);
      $(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      if (callback) callback();
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Populates all child drop downs on load
  var callback = function () {
    CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
  };

  CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups", callback);

  // Populates all child drop downs parent change
  $(".DeviceTypeDDL").change(function () {
    var callback = function () {
      CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
    };
    CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups", callback);
  });
  $(".ConfigGroupDDL").change(function () {
    CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
  });

  $(".MergeDeleteDDL").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      $("#ConfigValue").val("DELETE");
    }
    else {
      $("#ConfigValue").val("");
    }
  });
```